# Html error when downloading youtube video

Tags: html, winforms

I downloaded a Youtube downloader from Github it was a WPF and it works however I want to reproduce this C# for Windows App. The original code from WPF is:

```
public async Task BeginDownload()
{
    if (!CheckInputs())
        return;

    ChangeButtonStates(false);

    string link = videoLink.Text;
    string? downloadFormat = null;
    string savedDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.savedDirectory;

    if (saveMP3.IsChecked == true)
        downloadFormat = "mp3";
    else
        downloadFormat = "mp4";

    try
    {
        cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        // If the given URL contains "&list" it means it is playlist
        if (!link.Contains("&list"))
            await DownloadSingle(link, savedDirectory, downloadFormat);
        else
            await DownloadPlaylist(link, savedDirectory, downloadFormat);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: \"{ex.Message}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        }).Start();
    }

    ChangeButtonStates(true);
}
```

My code converted for use with windows form

```
public async Task BeginDownload()
{
    if (!CheckInputs())
        return;

    ChangeButtonStates(false);

    string link = videoLink.Text;
    string downloadFormat = null;
    string savedDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.savedDirectory;

    if (cmbDownloadType.SelectedIndex == 1)
        downloadFormat = "mp3";
    else
        downloadFormat = "mp4";

    try
    {
        cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        //// If the given URL contains "&list" it means it is playlist
        //if (!link.Contains("&list"))
        await DownloadSingle(link, savedDirectory, downloadFormat);
        //else
        //await DownloadPlaylist(link, savedDirectory, downloadFormat);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: \"{ex.Message}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }).Start();
    }

    ChangeButtonStates(true);
}
```

for simplicity I commented out playlist I can add it later I only want to start with a single download. When I run my code it get a html error not sure how to troubleshoot the error.

[image]

WPF code to download single

```
public async Task DownloadSingle(string link, string path, string format)
{
    // Needed for security
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, true);
    handler.UseCookies = false;

    // Get video data
    var youtube = new YoutubeClient(httpClient);
    var streamData = await youtube.Videos.GetAsync(link);
    var title = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(streamData.Title);

    var progress = new Progress<double>(value =>
    {
            // To split the progress bar into two halves, fill one half and then the next,
            // maximum of both progress bars is 50
            if (downloadProgressOne.Value != 50)
        {
            downloadProgressOne.Value = value * 100.00f;
        }
        else
        {
            downloadProgressTwo.Value = (value * 100.00f) - 50;
        }

            // Taskbar icon progress bar
            taskbarIcon.ProgressValue = value;

        downloadStatus.Text = $"Downloading... {Convert.ToInt32(value * 100.00f)}%";
    });

    try
    {
        // Download content
        await youtube.Videos.DownloadAsync(link, $"{path}\\{title}.{format}", o => o.SetContainer(format).SetPreset(ConversionPreset.UltraFast), progress, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Successfully cancelled the download of: \"{title}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }).Start();

        File.Delete($"{path}\\{title}.{format}");
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Failed to download video: \"{title}\" due to an error.\n\nReason: \"{ex.Message}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

        }).Start();

        return;
    }

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Successfully downloaded video: \"{title}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

    }).Start();
}

public async Task DownloadPlaylist(string link, string path, string format)
{
    // Create a string list incase any videos fail to download
    List<string> failedVideosTitles = new();
    string finalList = "";
    int failedVideosAmount = 0;

    // Needed for security
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, true);
    handler.UseCookies = false;

    // Get playlist data
    var youtube = new YoutubeClient(httpClient);
    var playlistData = await youtube.Playlists.GetAsync(link);
    var playlistName = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(playlistData.Title);
    var total = await youtube.Playlists.GetVideosAsync(link);
    var totalNumber = total.Count;

    int currentNumber = 0;

    // Foreach video in the playlist try to download them as the desired format
    await foreach (var video in youtube.Playlists.GetVideosAsync(playlistData.Id))
    {
        currentNumber++;
        var title = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(video.Title);

        // Skip download of video if it already exists
        if (File.Exists($"{path}\\{title}.{format}"))
        {
            downloadStatus.Text = $"Skipping {currentNumber}/{totalNumber}...";
            await Task.Delay(100);
            continue;
        }

        var progress = new Progress<double>(value =>
        {
            // To split the progress bar into two halves, fill one half and then the next,
            // maximum of both progress bars is 50
            if (value < 0.5f || downloadProgressOne.Value < 50)
            {
                downloadProgressOne.Value = value * 100.00f;
                downloadProgressTwo.Value = 0;
            }
            else
                downloadProgressTwo.Value = (value * 100.00f) - 50;

            // Taskbar icon progress bar
            taskbarIcon.ProgressValue = value;

            downloadStatus.Text = $"Downloading... {currentNumber}/{totalNumber} - {Convert.ToInt32(value * 100.00f)}%";
        });

        try
        {
            // Download content
            await youtube.Videos.DownloadAsync(video.Id, $"{path}\\{title}.{format}", o => o.SetContainer(format).SetPreset(ConversionPreset.UltraFast), progress, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Successfully cancelled the download of playlist: \"{playlistName}\".\n\nFiles have not been deleted.", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

            }).Start();

            File.Delete($"{path}\\{title}.{format}");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                // Increase the failed videos amount by one and add the title to the list
                failedVideosAmount++;
                failedVideosTitles.Add($"\"{title}\"");

                MessageBox.Show($"Skipping download of video: \"{title}\" due to an error.\n\nReason: \"{ex.Message}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

            }).Start();
        }
    }

    if (failedVideosAmount != 0)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Show a messagebox telling the user it failed to download X amount of videos
            MessageBox.Show($"Downloaded playlist: \"{playlistName}\" but failed to download {failedVideosAmount} of the videos.\n\nPress OK to see list of failed videos.", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

            // Loop for the length of the string list, build a final string containing
            // a list of titles of failed videos then display it in a messagebox for the user
            for (int i = 0; i < failedVideosTitles.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0) { finalList = $"{finalList}{i + 1}. {failedVideosTitles[i]}."; }
                else { finalList = $"{finalList}\n\n{i + 1}. {failedVideosTitles[i]}."; }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(finalList, "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }).Start();
    }
    else
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            // The entire playlist was downloaded successfully
            MessageBox.Show($"Successfully downloaded playlist: \"{playlistName}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }).Start();
    }
}
```

my converted code

```
public async Task DownloadSingle(string link, string path, string format)
{
    // Needed for security
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler, true);
    handler.UseCookies = false;

    // Get video data
    var youtube = new YoutubeClient(httpClient);
    var streamData = await youtube.Videos.GetAsync(link);
    var title = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(streamData.Title);

    var progress = new Progress<double>(value =>
    {
        // To split the progress bar into two halves, fill one half and then the next,
        // maximum of both progress bars is 50
        if (downloadProgressOne.Value != 50)
        {
            downloadProgressOne.Value = (int)(value * 100.00f);
        }
        else
        {
            downloadProgressTwo.Value = (int)((value * 100.00f) - 50);
        }

        // Taskbar icon progress bar
        //taskbarIcon.ProgressValue = value;

        downloadStatus.Text = $"Downloading... {Convert.ToInt32(value * 100.00f)}%";
    });

    try
    {
        // Download content
        await youtube.Videos.DownloadAsync(link, $"{path}\\{title}.{format}", o => o.SetContainer(format).SetPreset(ConversionPreset.UltraFast), progress, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Successfully cancelled the download of: \"{title}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }).Start();

        File.Delete($"{path}\\{title}.{format}");
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Failed to download video: \"{title}\" due to an error.\n\nReason: \"{ex.Message}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        }).Start();

        return;
    }

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Successfully downloaded video: \"{title}\".", "Downloader", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: What I found was an inner exception could not load System.Encoding.Codepages version = 6.0 does any one know how I get around the the version 6 issue when using framework  4.72 .net framework the other program uses .net core 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Argh rookie mistake just had to update the nuget package for codepages.